# Issue running two Oozie coordinator application simultaneously

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I am new to hadoop and oozie. I was trying to run two coordinator instances with the following details:
`CoordinatorOne` has a workflow job with single action(i.e java action ) in it. It runs 24/7 with some frequency. When I run another coordinator, say `CoordinatorTwo`, (which has a workflowjob with on single pig action in it) with the same frequency and a start time coinciding with the one of the materialized time of `CoordinatorOne` action, the second coordinator actions fails randomly (i.e. sometimes they succeed and sometimes they fail). I have tried checking the job's logs, but there no logs created. When I checked the info of the oozie action ID on the command line I found this error:

```
main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.pigmain], exit code [2]
```

I couldn't figure the problem. Please let me know if anyone has faced this kind of issue before.

Also, `CoordinatorOne`'s output is fed as input to `CoordinatorTwo`. `CoordinatorOne` never fails. The problem is with `CoordinatorTwo`, but it works fine when the first one is terminated.

Details of cluster:
2 node cluster with 4 Map and 2 reduce task capacity - CentOS VM's with 4gb ram each.
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0
Oozie client build version: 3.3.2-cdh4.3.0

PS: Let me know if I missed anything. Thanks so much!

CoordinatorOne and Two definitions below:

```
CoordinatorOne:

<coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4"  frequency="${frequency}" start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC" name="CoordinatorOne">

<controls>
    <timeout>3</timeout>
    <concurrency>1</concurrency>
</controls>

<datasets>
    <dataset name="OutputDataset" frequency="${frequency}" initial-instance="${start}" timezone="UTC">
    <uri-template>${namenode}/user/somefolder/Output/Test/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/${MINUTE}/itemdata</uri-template><done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
</datasets>

<output-events>
    <data-out name="Outputevent" dataset="OutputDataset">
     <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-out>
 </output-events>



 <action>
    <workflow>
       <app-path>${namenode}/user/somefolder/Input/Workflow</app-path>
       <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>namenode</name>
                <value>${namenode}</value>
            </property>
       <property>
                <name>jobtracker</name>
                <value>${jobtracker}</value>
            </property>
     <property>
                <name>queue_name</name>
                <value>${queue_name}</value>
            </property>
             <property>
                 <name>path</name>
                  <value>${coord:dataOut('Outputevent')}</value>
              </property>

          </configuration>
     </workflow>
 </action>     


</coordinator-app>


   CoordinatTwo:


<coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4"  frequency="${frequency}" start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC" name="CoordinatorTwo">

 <controls>
      <timeout>5</timeout>
       <concurrency>1</concurrency>
  </controls>

 <datasets>
      <dataset name="OutputDataset" frequency="${frequency}" initial-instance="${start}" timezone="UTC">
       <uri-template>${namenode}/user/somefolder/Output/Test/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/Somedata${MINUTE}</uri-template>
      <done-flag></done-flag>
       </dataset>
  <dataset name="InputDataset" frequency="${frequencyInput}" initial-instance="${startTimeofInputset}" timezone="UTC">
        <uri-template>${namenode}/user/somefolder/Output/Test/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/${MINUTE}</uri-template>
   <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
</datasets>
 <input-events>
    <data-in name="Inputevent" dataset="InputDataset">
      <instance>${coord:current(-1)}</instance>
      </data-in>
  </input-events>   
 <output-events>
    <data-out name="Outputevent" dataset="OutputDataset">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-out>
 </output-events>

  <action>
    <workflow>
     <app-path>${namenode}/user/somefolder/Input/WorkflowItem</app-path>
       <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>namenode</name>
                <value>${namenode}</value>
            </property>
       <property>
                <name>jobtracker</name>
                <value>${jobtracker}</value>
            </property>
     <property>
                <name>queue_name</name>
                <value>${queue_name}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                    <name>Inputpath</name>
                    <value>${coord:dataIn('Inputevent')}</value>
                  </property>
             <property>
                    <name>Outputpath</name>
                    <value>${coord:dataOut('Outputevent')}</value>
                  </property>

           </configuration>
     </workflow>
 </action>
```

`

Comment: Try to set oozie logger to DEBUG in oozie/conf/oozie-log4j.properties and then see if you can spot something suspicious.

Comment: Do different materializations of CoordinatorOne write to different directories (based on materialization time), or to the same directory? If latter, pig action in CoordinatorTwo obviously fails because of CoordinatorOne rewrites its input. It would be helpful if you post definitions of your coordinators.

Comment: Hi Dmitry ,thanks for the reply.Yes same directory but different files like:
somefolder/2013/12/26/somedata0
somefolder/2013/12/26/somedata5
somefolder/2013/12/26/somedata10,will there be any Conflict while coordinatorOne creates a file in same directory form which coordinatoTwo is trying to access previous succeeded files ?.

Comment: As far as I understand, CoordinatorOne creates files like /user/somefolder/Output/Test/2013/12/26/10/00/itemdata, and CoordinatorTwo reads from /user/somefolder/Output/Test/2013/12/26/10/00. If they start at the same time, then, as I wrote, data may not be ready when Pig runs and it fails. The solution - your java action produces empty "_SUCCESS" flag when data is ready and InputDataset in CoordinatorTwo doesn't specify <done-flag> (it will be "_SUCCESS" by default). This way CoordinatorTwo will wait for data.

Answer (score 0):

> CoordinatorOne's output is fed as input to CoordinatorTwo

Make sure that CoordinatorTwo waits for its input - see example [here](https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases) ("Triggering Coordinator Jobs When Data Directory is Available"). Pig action may fail if input doesn't exist or incomplete (see pig logs to confirm it).